# Reuse Abandoned Django User IDs?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a new public-facing Django/PostgreSQL-based web site that requires users to create a new username/password and then fill out a profile that requires three more screens (forms) after the initial username/password page to complete their membership.  As you would expect, I have a small number of users that don't complete the entire signup process leaving me with abandoned user IDs. Do either Django and/or PostgreSQL provide any convenient means of recovering and reusing these abandoned user IDs?

Comment: What if you commit the username and password to the database only after users finished filling out their profile?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why does it matter if the IDs are unused?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Because the id is kept in the session bucket and used on subsequent pages.  It's also used as the FK to data in other tables that is collected in those subsequent pages.